# How to create a loop to send a message if the channel last message was sent X minutes ago? [discord.py]

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to add a customizable chat revival command feature that sends a topic to revive the chat after nobody has spoken for X minutes, X can be set by an admin, I have asked a similar question before but the answer I got doesn't apply here.

So how the feature works: An admin enables the feature by executing a command and specifying the number of minutes they want, then the minutes are saved to a database.

The problem is not with saving the minutes to the database, it works well, the problem is with creating a loop to check if the channel last message date exceeded the limit set by the admins.

I have tried several ways, Like using `asyncio.sleep` and `wait_for()`, but they affected the other commands, so they aren't the right way to go, and I tried this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if str(message.channel.id) in data: # Check if the admins has set a number of mintues
        keepLooping = True
        timer = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=delay) # delay is the time set by admins, pulled from the database.
        while keepLooping:
            if timer < message.channel.last_message.created_at and message.channel.last_message.author != bot.user:
                await message.channel.send("Random Topic Here")
                return
   
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

I have asked some people in some servers, they told me the way above is not good for memory, so I am also assuming it is not a way to go either. One friend has told me to use the discord.py tasks, but I am not sure how to implement them.

Any help regarding this case will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/). It's not a excellent solution but it will work for you.

```
from discord.ext import tasks
import datetime
@tasks.loop(seconds=10.0)
async def checker():
    channel = # you should define the channel here
    last_mes = channel.last_message.created_at
    counter = # you should define the 'X' minutes here
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now-last_mes >= datetime.timedelta(minutes=counter):
        await message.channel.send("Random Topic Here")
        return
```

You can do that and also you should add `checker.start()` end of to the your code.